# Functions don't execute in desired order

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, function

I am making an app where I have to check for login status first and then have to decide which ViewController to present. And because I have to use a lot of URLs to hit and get value throughout the project, I have made a separate file. That file takes the URL and returns the `Dictionary` which I need.

I call the method at `viewDidLoad` and use the value in other function called `handleData`. But every time `handleData` gets executed before the function in the separate class. Is there a solution for this so that I can have functions execute in desired order?

Here are the snippets:

```
class LoadingViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var activity: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    let fetchData = FetchingData()
    var ifHasAccount: NSDictionary!

    var acStatus: String?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        handleData()
        ifHasAccount = NSDictionary()
        activity.startAnimating()
    }
    func handleData(){

        fetchData.urlForHit = "Some URL"
        ifHasAccount = fetchData.fetchData()
        print(ifHasAccount)
    }
}
```

and for the other class i.e.,

> FetchingData()

it is:

```
class FetchingData{


    private var _urlForHit: String?
    var _aDictionary: NSDictionary?

    var urlForHit: String{
        get{
            return _urlForHit!
        }
        set{
            _urlForHit = newValue
        }
    }

    func fetchData() -> NSDictionary {
        var aDictionary = NSDictionary()
        let urlToHit = URL(string: _urlForHit!)
        var request = URLRequest(url: urlToHit!)
        request.setValue(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "DEVICEID")! as? String, forHTTPHeaderField: "deviceId")
        request.setValue(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "FCMID")! as? String, forHTTPHeaderField: "fcmId")
        request.setValue("iOS", forHTTPHeaderField: "deviceType")
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil{
                print((error?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, 200..<300 ~= response.statusCode else {print("Response out of range"); return}
            if data != nil{
                do{
                    aDictionary = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
                    print(aDictionary)
                }
            }
            else
            {
                print("Data nil")
            }
        }
        task.resume()

        self._aDictionary = aDictionary
        return _aDictionary!
    }
}
```

Comment: Network operations complete asynchronously; You need to pass a completion closure and act on the network response in the closure. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203556/returning-data-from-async-call-in-swift-function

Comment: As @Paulw11 said, do that check on your `if data != nil` block, or call a function from there to perform your check.

Comment: This is working now. Thank you very much!